# Why does `psql --file` misinterpret tilde?

Tags: linux, shell, postgresql

Earlier I used pg_dump to create a database backup in my home directory called book_dump.sql.

I want to restore the backup to an empty database called book.

To restore the backup, I tried this command:

```
psql book --file=~/book_dump.sql
```

It failed with this message:

```
~/book_dump.sql: No such file or directory
```

I tried again with an absolute path:

```
psql book --file=/home/user/book_dump.sql
```

This time it worked.

I tried using a space after `--file` instead of equals:

```
psql book --file ~/book_dump.sql
```

This works as well.

Why doesn't tilde work when I use the equals sign?

Is this a problem problem particular to psql, or is it a Linux problem?

Can I change something to make it work as I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the shell (not psql) that is responsible for expanding the `~` character.

Assuming bash, see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html:

> If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character (‘~’), all of the
>   characters up to the first unquoted slash (or all characters, if there
>   is no unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix

Tilde preceded by an equal sign is somehow a special case. They say:

> Each variable assignment is checked for unquoted tilde-prefixes
>   immediately following a ‘:’ or the first ‘=’. In these cases, tilde
>   expansion is also performed. Consequently, one may use file names with
>   tildes in assignments to PATH, MAILPATH, and CDPATH, and the shell
>   assigns the expanded value.

`--file=~/foo` is not a variable assignment so the tilde expansion is not applied. I guess `--file=$HOME/foo` should be used instead.

On the other hand, `file=~/foo` as a command does assign `/home/user/foo` to `$file`.

Also I see that `echo bar=~/foo` will output `bar=/home/daniel/foo` despite it not being an assignment, some there is apparently some fuzz factor in the above rule.

Comment: Since I discovered that psql accepts spaces instead of equals, I always use spaces. It's simpler that way. Thanks for the well-researched answer!